# MVC5 EF6 UserRights

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rights-management

I wonder what is the best practise for checking actually logged user's rightsfor in MVC appliaction. I would like to do this on the views and on the controllers.

Actually I can check if actual logged user is in the role like that:

```
User.IsInRole("roleName");
```

I have table with rights. Every right contain name and Enum right representation. What I want to accomplish is extension method for IPrincipal or IIdentity so I could check rights of the user like that:

Example extension method:

```
    public static class MyPrincipal
    {
       public static string HasRight(this IPrincipal principal, EnumRight right)
       {
           // THIS would be place where I would check if a user have right with specific enum.
           return true/false;
       }
    }
```

and then on the view or controller I could use this like that:

```
if(User.HasRight(EnumRight.AddDocuments) )
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

1. Is it good practise or how can I do similar mechanism simpler? Maybe independent static class not extension?
2. How can i get actual user Id in my extension method to get from database any data which is needed to check if user has rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would implement an authorization filter, and apply it to your action method. Here is the [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) how you can implement action filters.